# For WebSphere Liberty Profile, backslash character inside bootstrap.properties file

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am having issue with the '\' (backslash) character inside bootstrap.properties file.

I first define a variable within bootstrap.properties file:

```
var1=AB\AC
```

Then, I define a jndiEntry inside server.xml file:

```
<jndiEntry value="${var1}" jndiName="jndi/var1" id="var1">
```

When I look up jndi entry in my code, the '\' is lost. If I use double backslash, i.e., '\\', then what I get is a forward slash, i.e., 'AB/AC'.

How can I input '\' character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liberty will perform path normalization on all variables unless the attribute is defined as a password type. The only way to get around this currently would be to include the backslash character in server.xml rather than bootstrap.properties.

For example, in server.xml:

> ```
> <jndiEntry value="${var1}\${var2}" jndiName="jndi/var1" id="var1">
> ```

bootstrap.properties:

> ```
> var1=AB
> var2=BC
> ```

Comment: This workaround does work. If you put backslash directly in the server.xml file, i.e., <jndiEntry value="AB\AC" jndiName="jndi/var1" id="var1"/>, that backslash will be turned into a forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

According to Liberty documentation, path normalization is performed on all variables located in bootstrap.properties file

> by replacing repeated forward and backward slashes with a single
>   forward slash, unless the value starts with double forward or backward
>   slashes, which remain unchanged.

However, according to their "Best practices" [section](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_setup_vars.html):

> If you need to set the value of a variable to contain repeated forward
>   slashes, as are sometimes used for JDBC driver connection URLs, break
>   the value into two parts at the double slashes. By placing the double
>   forward slashes as the initial characters, normalization is avoided.
>   For example, to store the value "jdbc:db2://host_name.com", use two
>   variables:
>
> URL_PART_1="jdbc:db2:" 
>   URL_PART_2="//host_name.com"